# Error in installing ingress-nginx helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress

I am installing nginx ingress controller through helm chart and pods are not coming up. Got some issue with the permission.

Chart link - https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx

I am using latest version 4.2.1

I done  debugging as stated here https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/4061
also tried to run as root  user **runAsUser: 0**

I think i got this issue after cluster upgrade from 1.19 to 1.22. Previously it was working fine.

Any suggestion what i need to do to fix that?

> unexpected error storing fake SSL Cert: could not create PEM
> certificate file
> /etc/ingress-controller/ssl/default-fake-certificate.pem: open
> /etc/ingress-controller/ssl/default-fake-certificate.pem: permission
> denied

Comment: I would suggest, ommitting this parameter, so the image would be created or alternatively create a new test pod with the same volumes, and trying to exec into that pod/container and then you will see where the problem is.

Comment: I tried setting image pull policy to always. i can able to acess the secrests with defult service accont  in sample pod. But i cant set defulat service account in that helm chart

Comment: You do not need a serviceAccount to access secrets. Also you can modify the service account in the values.yaml file under ```defaultBackend.serviceAccount```

Comment: But still it was not able to read secrets. What should i do so that it can able to read secrets

Answer (score 1):

You obviously have permission problem. Looking at the Chart you specified, the are multiple values of `runAsUser` for different config.

```
controller.image.runAsUser: 101
controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.runAsUser: 2000
defaultBackend.image.runAsUser: 65534
```

I'm not sure why these are different, but if possible -

Try to delete your existing chart, and fresh install it.

If the issue still persist - check the deployment / pod events, see if the cluster alerts you about something.

Also worth noting, there were breaking changes in 1.22 to `Ingress` resource.
Check [this](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/07/14/upcoming-changes-in-kubernetes-1-22/#what-to-do) and this [links](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/08/04/kubernetes-1-22-release-announcement/#major-changes) from the official release notes.

Answer (score 0):

That issue occurred because all worker node is not properly upgraded as a result ingress controller cant setup properly so i tried to install it on particular node having same version as cluster then it works properly